# How to increase the duration and usage of TLS connection

Tags: java, ssl, https, jax-rs, tls1.2

I am using **JAX-RS** and **SOAP** protocol on my service

Im finding a way to utilize the TLS connection made when initializing http client connection and handshake, so the subsequent connections will reuse the created TLS.

When I enable the ssl debugging, within the 20 transactions 5 handshakes were made. What I want is to override that behavior something like:

'for 20 transactions only 1 handshake were made' --> all transactions used same TLS connection. OR

prolong the duration of TLS connection like 10mins (*if that is compliant*)

I have tried sending the following in the header:

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=10
```

What is the proper way to do it in **JAX-RS**?

I also tried customizing the http headers (see screenshot of code below)

```
Map<String, List<String>> httpHeaders = new HashMap<>();
httpHeaders.put("Connection", Collections.singletonList("Keep-Alive"));
httpHeaders.put("Keep-Alive", Collections.singletonList("timeout=10, max=10"));
bindProvider.getRequestContext().put(HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS, httpHeaders);
```

The load test results did not really differ vs without those headers. So I'm thinking if there is another layer of configuration in JAX-RS that overrides this customized headers.

Comment: These headers are purely a suggestion. Client and server are allowed to close the connection anytime after a response was finished.